# How to process req from phonegap on node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova

I have this Android app build on Cordova-2.2.0, I'm using node on the server side.
There is a part where an image needs to be send to the server, either from the camera or a file. The image is sucesfully uploaded to the server, but when it is saved it seems to be damaged. If I open the image on the notepad it has this "extra header" on the file. Besides that all the file is just the same.
Here is my code on the client:

```
function getPhoto() {

        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,
                                    function(message) { alert('No image selected');},
                                    { quality: 50, 
                                    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY }
                                    );

    }

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var largeImage = document.getElementById('Image');
        largeImage.style.display = 'block';
        largeImage.src = imageURI;
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpg";

        options.chunkedMode = false;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://10.8.13.92:8082", win, fail, options);
    }
```

And this is the code on the server:

```
http.createServer(function (req,res){
var fs = require('fs');
var imagen = fs.createWriteStream("imagen.jpg",{'flags':'a'});

req.addListener('response',function(response){

})
});

req.addListener('data',function(chunk){
    imagen.write(chunk,encoding='binary');
});

req.on('end',function(){
    imagen.end();

    console.log('File written');
});

}).listen(8082);
```

I know the problem is on the server, but I can't find anything different from this to write the .jpg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From documentation:**

> The FileTransfer object provides a way to upload files to a remote
>   server using an HTTP multi-part POST request.

You are trying to writing all reqest data to image file but request data is not just binnary image data. It contains file in HTTP multi-part format and need to be parsed before writing to file.

Simplest way to do it - using [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) with bodyParser middleware.

Sample app:

```
var http = require('http');
var connect = require('connect');

var app = connect();
var server = http.createServer(app);
app.use(connect.bodyParser());
app.use(function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files); // Here is object with uploaded files
});

server.listen(8082);
```

You can find path to uploaded file in `req.files` object and move it to needed destination.